# Parsing String Into List of Integers with Ranges

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, parsing

I have a bunch of strings I would like to parse that all look like this:

```
"1001, 1003, 1005-1010"
"1015"
"900-903"
"200, 202-209, 211-220"
```

Sometimes these strings will be just one integer, sometimes multiple separated by commas, and sometimes a range, and the latter two can appear simultaneously in a single string in any order.

What I would like to do is create a function that takes in the string and returns a collection of integers by parsing the string. So for example the first string should return:

```
[1001, 1003, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010]
```

What are some smart ways to do this in .NET 4.0?

Comment: What have you tried so far? A simple approach could be, split by ",", check if token contains "-", if so, loop through its bounds and add them to the final array, otherwise add the token. Then, just re-order the array.

Comment: @RodrigoSilva I tried an approach where I have two pointers where one goes along until it finds either a '-' or a ',' and parses what's between the first and 2nd pointer then moves them both up and in the case of '-' does a loop to add everything in the range. However I'm having trouble avoiding situations where I'll go outside the index bounds and deciding when something has gone wrong and throwing exceptions when it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET 4.0 means you got LINQ available, so you should probably use it:

```
var input = "1001, 1003, 1005-1010";

var results = (from x in input.Split(',')
               let y = x.Split('-')
               select y.Length == 1
                 ? new[] { int.Parse(y[0]) }
                 : Enumerable.Range(int.Parse(y[0]), int.Parse(y[1]) - int.Parse(y[0]) + 1)
               ).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Linq, how does this solution handle things like lack of or extra spaces before or after commas and things like invalid ranges like "1001-900" or "1001-"?

Comment: It will handle additional spaces, but it will fail with invalid ranges.

Comment: In that case this is perfect for my needs. I would still like to see some non-Linq solutions from other people though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Traditional loop that might be easier to read:

```
string input = "1001, 1003, 1005-1010";

List<int> result = new List<int>();
foreach (string part in input.Split(','))
{
    int i = part.IndexOf('-');
    if (i == -1)
    {
        result.Add(int.Parse(part));
    }
    else
    {
        int min = int.Parse(part.Substring(0, i));
        int max = int.Parse(part.Substring(i + 1));
        result.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very nice it offers improved readability over the Linq solution while also only being slightly more lines of code.